# Connecting between node and bootnode gives error=expired

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, bootnodes

I am trying to form a private network. If I run the bootnode and node on the same VM, the blockchain runs perfectly. However if the bootnode is running on one VM and the node is on a second VM, sometimes they connect but other times I get the `err=expired` at the bootnode console.

[image: bootnode console]

I connect the node with the bootnode with following command:

[image: connecting node]

Am I missing something?

Deep heartedly thank for any help.